# Implementing annotation based spring security

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I need to implement spring security in my web application I have created user repository custom `Service` class and also `POJO` required to communicate with backend and i am not using in-memory configuration where I am using,

```
@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }
```

Dependencies in `pom.xml`,

```
<spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version> <spring.security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

While running the application I am getting below error

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class]
>   cannot be opened because it does not exist

but jar is already downloaded

Comment: having a 'version' property and a dependency is not the same, let's start with that. how did you set your dependencies? Why not going for the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

add maven dependencies in the deployment assembly and try again.(I guess you are using eclipse ide) open the project properties got to deployment assembly and click on add and select Java build path entries. move next and select maven dependencies

Comment: No. Maven dependencies were already there in deployment assembly still removed them and added back,But it was giving the same error. Thank you

Comment: please can you share the full log trace